# Router issue every once in a while

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Every once in a while, when building my app, I am receiving this weird issue:

> EXCEPTION: Error during instantiation of Router! (NavComponent -> Auth -> Router).
>   ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Route config should contain exactly one "component", "loader", or "redirectTo" property.

It is weird as it only shows up very rearly, not every single time.

My `NavComponent` uses `Auth`, and has a `RouterLink`. Here it is:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {NgIf} from 'angular2/common';
import {RouterLink} from 'angular2/router';
import {Auth} from '../auth.injectable'


@Component({
    selector: 'navigation',
    templateUrl: 'app/navigation/Navigation.html',
    directives: [NgIf, RouterLink]
})

export class NavComponent{
    private user:any;
    private isLogged:boolean;
    constructor(private _auth:Auth) {
        this.user = _auth.getUser();
        if(this.user.username){
            this.isLogged = true;
        }
    }
    logout(){
        this._auth.logout();
    }
}
```

My `Auth` service uses `@Inject(Router) private _router`, and looks like that:

```
import {Inject} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';
import {Router} from "angular2/router";
import {EventEmitterService} from "../common/EventEmitter.service";

export class Auth {
    public user: any = sessionStorage.getItem('user') ? JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('user')) : {};
    constructor(@Inject(Http) private _http, @Inject(Router) private _router, @Inject(EventEmitterService) private _eventEmitterService){
        _eventEmitterService.logout.subscribe((data)=>{
            _router.navigate(['Login']);
        })
    }

    login(username,password){
        var user = {
            username: username,
            password: password
        };
        this._http.post('/authentication/login',user)
            .subscribe(
                success =>{
                    this.user = success.json();
                    sessionStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(success.json()));
                    this._router.navigate(['Dashboard']);
                },
                error =>{
                    this.user.authError = true;
                });
    }

    getUser(){
        return this.user;
    }
}
```

and I inject it like that in `Boot.js`:

```
bootstrap(MyApp, [
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    Auth,
    provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy}),
    provide(APP_BASE_HREF, {useValue: '/'})
    ....])
```

Here is my `@RouteConfig`:

```
@RouteConfig([
    {path: '/', redirectTo: ['Dashboard']},
    {path: '/login', name: 'Login', component: LoginComponent},
    {path: '/dashboard', name: 'Dashboard', component: DashboardComponent}
])
```

Any ideas? It should work every time, not 99% of time.

Comment: Sounds weird. Hard to tell with the information you provided. I guess this requires at least a working Plunker that shows how things are connected.

Comment: I know. I am very confused too. I have no idea where the issue comes from. I thought it was caused by imports order, but that didnt helped much. I use gulp for building, maybe there is an error somwhere there...

Comment: how  does your nav @component decorator look like?

Comment: @micronyks, I've added NavComponent to the question

Comment: apart from answer - use `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES` instead of `RouterLink` in the list of directives, this includes `RouterLink` as well, also better to understand your problem if you provide `RouteConfig` coding

Comment: No need to list `NgIf`. It's part of `COMMON_DIRECTIVES` which are available universally without listing them anywhere.

Comment: I've added Auth, and RouterConfig :)

Comment: `@Inject(Router)` in `@Inject(Router) private _router` is redundant if you add the type like `constructor(private _router:Router) {}`. `@Inject()` is only necessary if you don't add a type to the parameter or if you use a string key or an `OpaqueToken`.

Comment: Actually it won't work if I use it ilke you've said. Then I receive an error of :ReferenceError: router_1 is not defined. Auth is a singleton, its not an provider.